# Multi entry Schengen visa

Tags: schengen-visas

We have a multi-entry visa from 15-7-2016 until 15-7-2017. The calculator isn't working and keeps giving an error.

We were already in the Schengen Area on these dates:

15-7-2016 until 26-9-2016 and from 5-1-2017 until 29-1-2017

We want to go again from 6-5-2017 until 14-7-2017

Is this okay and will it be allowed?

Comment: What calculator are you talking about? What is your nationality?

Comment: Is [this the tool you're using?](https://ec.europa.eu/assets/home/visa-calculator/calculator.htm?lang=en)

Comment: I Just checked your dates on the calculator and it shows "The stay may be authorised for up to: 90 day(s)"

Comment: That's not what I get. I get 65 days. So yes, allowed.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to depend on the calculator, you can also note that by the time you enter on May 6, you will **have been outside of Schengen for more than 90 consecutive days** (namely, say, the full months of February, March, and April, plus May 1st).

This, in itself, is enough to make everything that came *before* those 90 days irrelevant for the purpose of complying with the 90/180 day rule.

Thus, as far as 90/180 is concerned, when you enter on May 6 you're in the same situation as if you have no prior trips at all.

Answer (score 1):

Today's date is populated automatically in "Date of entry/Control" (and needs to be a specific format):

[image: Schengen calculator]

The above (as reference by @Dorothy) is the official calculator and does appear to be working. What it is saying is that on July 14, 2017 you will not have overstayed, given the data as shown, and indeed could extend your proposed trip by a further 20 days without exceeding the limit - *provided* (as @phoog has pointed out!) you have a visa that is valid for the further 20 days (at least).

On the proposed date of entry (May 6) of previous trips only the 25-day January trip is relevant since the one in 2016 ended more than 180 days earlier. So on May 6 you would have used up 26 (25 +1) of the allowed 90 days. This keeps increasing up to 84 days utilised on July 3 (25+59) and then levels off, as further days for your proposed trip are offset by days from your January trip that cease to count, for being longer ago than 180 days. This would continue to be the case until July 28, 14 days after the end of your proposed trip at which point your utilisation would go up again (if you extended that far) so you would only be allowed a further 6 days (84 + 6 = 90) hence the `20` 'spare' (14 + 6).

All the above though just concerns counting days. You are only allowed in the Schengen area while your visa is valid and since your current visa expires July 15 you must leave before July 16, unless you obtain a valid new visa.

Comment: "could extend your proposed trip by a further 20 days": they would of course need another visa to do that, since the visa they now hold expires on 15 July.  The visa application could be filed at any time after 7 January: "Holders of a multiple-entry visa may lodge the application before the expiry of the visa valid for a period of at least six months."

Comment: @pnuts isn't the date of entry 6/5/2017 not 14/7/17? That's the planned date of exit.